# Is there a way to resize displayed pictures?

Tags: support, images

Can we change a picture size when we display it from a linked website? It seems that the picture is always displayed at maximum size.

Comment: All of the imgur options should be available; see [here](https://api.imgur.com/models/image) and scroll down to Thumbnails.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74312/thumbnail-image-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

When you go to the 'add an image', it provides an option to 'provide a link from the web'. Let's use [this](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/lotr/images/a/a0/Saruman_%21.jpeg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/220?cb=20140426125614) image of Saruman for example.

This is it's natural size:
[image]

Here I'm adding an 'l' at the end of the imgur link at the bottom to make it *large*.
[image]

Her's an 'm' for *medium*.
[image]

And here's an 's' for *small*.
[image]

(Admittedly, in this image, there isn't much difference between the first three. With a humongous image, however, there is a noticeable difference.)

Comment: It looks like it messes with the background with png images...

Comment: @Bebs I'm %99.99 sure it only changes the size.

Comment: Feel free to try here :) http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146325/has-brienne-really-seen-dunks-shield

Comment: On mobile these are all identical, except the smallest :-)

Comment: Best practice is to inline a smaller image, but to link to the fullsize image.

Comment: Regardless of the size chosen, the maximum width will still be based on the post area. So smaller screens or mobile app may still not ever see a giant version (but they may have to use data to download the full version, which is why I prefer using medium)